# ¿Cómo puedo girar un botón a 90 grados?

Tags: android-studio, xml

¿Cómo podría girar un botón en modo vertical? No quiero hacer una aplicación que gire un botón sino que en mi aplicación aparezca el `button` a 90 grados.. ingrese en el xml pero no hay caso.

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.589"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="187dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si te referirás a esto, pero solamente modificando los atributos width y height, se puede conseguir. Dándole unas dimensiones apropiadas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.diego3l.botonvertical.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mi_btn"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:text="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]